# How to add a new row at the beginning of a filtered office-js Excel table?

Tags: office-js

Using office-js in an Excel add-in, I use this code to add a row in a table:

```
Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem('mySheet');
    const table = sheet.tables.getItemAt(0);

    const newValues=[['val1', 'val2']];
    table.rows.add(0, newValues);
    await context.sync();
});
```

It works well until I filter the table (by using the built-in filters in the table header). Then I get this error :
[image: InsertDeleteConflict on TableRowCollection.add]

I try to do it in another way, using "table.getDataBodyRange();" :

```
    const range = table.getDataBodyRange();
    const rangeRow = range.getRow(0);
    rangeRow.getEntireRow().insert('Down');
    await context.sync();
    const insertedRange = range.getRow(0);
    insertedRange.values = [['val1', 'val2']];
    await context.sync();
```

In this case, the row is created, but the values are not set.

Did I miss something or is there another way to create a new row, in the filtered Table, containing my values?

[edit] This new row should be added at the beginning of the table.

Answer (score 0):

the trick here is to insert at the end of the table. if you pass "null" to table.rows.add it will append a row.

also you can simplify your code a lot, check this out:
 (btw, [here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/453a73497aa01506555ad8a4378e0435) you can restore in script lab.)

```js
async function run() {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        const newValues = [['val1', 'val3']];
        const table = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem('Sheet1').tables.getItem("Table1").rows.add(null, newValues);
        await context.sync();
   });
}
```

Comment: I would like to add the new row at the beginning of the table for convenience purpose. I will edit my question to make it clearer.